# NSBox Focus Ring?

Tags: objective-c, xcode, cocoa, user-interface, osx-lion

Is there a way to focus on an NSBox and draw the focus ring for that box?
I thought [box drawFocusRingMask]; could be something similar, but nothing happens. 
I just need the box to have a focus ring around it when a button has been clicked.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What does it mean for an NSBox to have focus?  What would it do with the key events it would receive?  You might be able to achieve something by subclassing NSBox and overriding `-acceptsFirstResponder` to return YES, but then you'd have to do something with the key events you'd receive.

Comment: @KenThomases I meant to draw the focus ring for the box when saying it to have the focus. I just need a box or something that would draw a focus ring around the border when I need it to. Is there a simple way to do it? I tried subclassing NSBox and overriding acceptsFirstResponder but it didn't have any effect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you're deploying to 10.7 or later, you can make a custom view class (perhaps a subclass of NSBox) and have it override the following methods:

```
- (BOOL)acceptsFirstResponder {
    return YES;
}
- (void)drawFocusRingMask {
    NSRectFill([self bounds]);
}
- (NSRect)focusRingMaskBounds {
    return [self bounds];
}
```

If subclassing NSBox, you can use `-borderRect` instead of `bounds`, if you prefer.

---

Edit: you may be able to use the pre-10.7-style of focus ring drawing.  You might do something like:

```
-(void)drawRect:(NSRect)rect
{
    NSResponder* fr = [[self window] firstResponder];
    if ([fr isKindOfClass:[NSView class]] && [(NSView*)fr isDescendantOf:self])
    {
        [NSGraphicsContext saveGraphicsState];
        NSSetFocusRingStyle(NSFocusRingOnly);
        [[NSBezierPath bezierPathWithRect:NSInsetRect([self bounds],4,4)] fill];
        [NSGraphicsContext restoreGraphicsState];
    }
    // ... normal drawing, possibly invoking super ...
}
```

The view would also have to watch for changes in the first responder and invoke `-setKeyboardFocusRingNeedsDisplayInRect:` on itself.  Plus, it may need to call `-setFocusRingType:` on itself during setup with `NSFocusRingTypeExterior`, although that may be the default, depending on the superclass.

Comment: Thanks for the response. It now creates a focus ring, but it only creates it when I click on the title of the nsbox. However, I want it to be shown when anywhere inside of the nsbox is clicked (I'm not going to have a title). If I call drawFocusRingMask, it fills in the entire nsbox with a black color. Is there a way to show the focus ring not just when the title has been clicked but anywhere inside the box?

Comment: This isn't how focus rings work.  Especially in 10.7 and later, where the AppKit handles much more of the focus ring stuff automatically.  Maybe you should stop thinking in terms of a focus ring and make a custom view that draws itself differently (in a custom manner) whenever the first responder is one of its descendant views.

Comment: I thought of an approach using the pre-10.7 focus ring drawing technique and edited my answer.